# Changing Delegate signature in library to omit an argument does not break applications using it

Tags: c#

Consider the following code in a class library:

```
public class Service
{
    public delegate string Formatter(string s1, string s2);

    public void Print(Formatter f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f("a", "b"));
    }
}
```

And here's a console application that uses it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    s = new Service();
    s.Print(Concat);
}

static string Concat(string s1, string s2)
{
    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", s1, s2);
}
```

So far it prints "*a-b*", just as one would expect.

Now, I change the class library as follows:

```
public class Service
{
    public delegate string Formatter(string s1);

    public void Print(Formatter f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f("a"));
    }
}
```

I.e. I removed one parameter from the delegate. I compile the class library only and overwrite the dll sitting next to the console app (console app is **not** recompiled). I'd expect that this is a breaking change in the library and if I execute the app, it finds the mismatch, resulting in some runtime exception.

In contrast, when I run the app there's no exception at all, and I get the stunning output "*-a*". When I debug, I can see that the Concat method (with 2 parameters) is called, the call stack level below shows Print calling to f("a") (one parameter), no error indication anywhere. Most interestingly, in Concat s1 is null, s2 is "a".

I also played around with different changes to the signature (adding parameters,  changing parameter type) mostly with the same result. When I changed the type of s2 from string to int I got an exception, but not when the Concat method was called, but when it tried to call string.Format.

I tried it with .NET target framework 4.5.1 and 3.5, x86 and x64.

Can anyone answer whether this is the expected behaviour or a bug? It seems pretty dangerous to me.

Comment: What happens if you add a parameter instead of removing one?

Comment: Heh, yeah, I can repro the behaviour; that ... kinda looks like a CLR bug? I agree that it certainly isn't intuitive

Comment: what is *especially* curious is that it even passes IL inspection - `peverify` is perfectly happy with it (although maybe this simply can't be done in IL, and needs to be deferred to runtime). Essentially, the `native int` parameter to the delegate constructor (representing the function) is not verified for a match, it seems

Comment: @Michael: I would not guess it, but when adding string s3 parameter the same thing happens: s1 is null and s2 is "a". I would not be that suprised about "a" and "b" or even "b" and "c" (I passed "c" as s3).

Comment: @Mark: yes, I also tried ngen, which also worked fine on it

Comment: Of course, one takeaway here is: don't do that :)

Comment: When you : 

> I removed one parameter from the delegate. I compile the class
> library only and overwrite the dll sitting next to the console app
> (console app is not recompiled).

It is certainly a breaking change in the library but AFAIK the problem is that when you rebuild your Library you're still using the old .dll as you haven't compiled your console application. 

Try to re-build console app instead of running it.

Comment: @Fabjan: No, I'm replacing the library dll that is used by the app in the bin\Debug dir of the app (simulating the installation of a new lib version). The app cannot be rebuilt, as it is using the delegate with the wrong number of parameters causing a compiler error.

Comment: http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-file-viewer.html should give the answer. It can break on JIT events and show disassembly alongside the IL, marking the current instruction in both. http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/documentation/pebrowse-pro-interactive-debugger-tutorial-initializing-clr.html is the .NET-specific part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler repro - basically, I'm using the "under the hood" constructor on the delegate type (the one that the IL uses) to pass a method target with the wrong signature, and... it works fine (by which I mean it doesn't throw an exception - it behaves just like your code):

```
using System;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // resolve the (object, IntPtr) ctor
        var ctor = typeof(Func<string, string>).GetConstructors()[0];

        // resolve the target method
        var mHandle = typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Concat))
            .MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
        object target = null; // because: static

        // create delegate instance
        var del = (Func<string, string>)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { target, mHandle });
        var result = del("abc");
        Console.WriteLine(result); // "-abc"
    }
    public static string Concat(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", s1, s2);
    }
}
```

This is not really an explanation. But it might be helpful if you want to ask someone more CLR-expert! I would have *expected* the delegate constructor to have complained loudly about the target being incorrect.

At a guess (pure speculation), it is a case of: if you're passing an `IntPtr` (native int), then you're entirely on your own - the code does the fastest thing possible. It does seem like a nasty trap for the unwary, though!

As for why `s2` has the value and `s1` is empty: I *guess* that is because the stack builds *down* (not up), hence in a two parameter method, `arg1` is the parameter **immediately adjacent** to the previous position on the stack. When we pass a single value instead of two, we only put one value underneath, so `s2` has a value, and `s1` is undefined (could be garbage from previous code).

Comment: Regarding the values of s1 and s2 I had the same guess. Though adding a parameter s3 also has the same result (s1 is null and s2 is "a"), whereas with the stack layout explanation two of the three passed parameters should be picked.

Comment: Interesting that adding one more parameter (s3) to Concat (and using it in string.Format) results in AccessViolationException.